# queuable interface issue

Tags: queueable-interface

I have two separate classes for making callouts(class One & class Two) and I am calling both of these classes in  another seperate class.wherein I would like to send the filter callouts first after which sendData callout should be passed so I am enqueuing senddata with filter class and calling both the class in third class

Class One:

```
public class SendFilter implements Queueable,Database.AllowsCallouts {
 public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
//Grouping mulitple filter events and passing it as a single callout
//callout logic 
System.enqueueJob(new SendData()); 
}
}
```

Class Two:

```
public class SendData implements Queueable,Database.AllowsCallouts {
 public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
//callout logic
}
}
```

Class Three:

```
 global with sharing class GSScMasterDataSync{
    public Pagereference next() {
     ID jobID1 = System.enqueueJob(new SendData());
     ID jobID = System.enqueueJob(new SendFilter());
    }

}
```

I am getting the following exception for sendfilter class as

> "Maximum callout depth has been reached"

Any suggestion on why I am getting this exceptions? I am queuing only one job with it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a future callout webservice method and enqueued the  Queueable class in this way.Now I am getting the expected response

```
  global with sharing class GSScMasterDataSync{
        public Pagereference next() {
      sendfilter(LoadType);
    }
    @Future(callout=true)
      webservice static void SendFilter(String LoadType) {
     //logic for filter
//calling queueable class here
     ID jobID1 = System.enqueueJob(new SendData());
    }
```